# Pandas add rows based on date

Tags: python, date, pandas, addition

I have a pandas dataframe with a column as date

`2015-11-01
2015-12-01
2016-01-01
2016-03-01
2016-03-01
2016-10-01
2016-10-01
2016-12-01
2017-03-01`

I want to insert two rows,
1. a row at the beginning by for previous month of first row 
2. a row at end for the next month of last row

to get desired output as,
`2015-10-01
2015-11-01
2015-12-01
2016-01-01
2016-03-01
2016-03-01
2016-10-01
2016-10-01
2016-12-01
2017-03-01
2017-04-01`

What is the pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

a = df.loc[1, 'date'] -  pd.offsets.MonthBegin()
b = df.loc[len(df.index) - 1, 'date'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin()
df = pd.DataFrame([a] + df['date'].tolist() + [b], columns=['date'])
print (df)
         date
0  2015-11-01
1  2015-11-01
2  2015-12-01
3  2016-01-01
4  2016-03-01
5  2016-03-01
6  2016-10-01
7  2016-10-01
8  2016-12-01
9  2017-03-01
10 2017-04-01
```

Or:

```
df.index = df.index + 1
df.loc[0, 'date'] = df.loc[1, 'date'] -  pd.offsets.MonthBegin()
df.loc[len(df.index), 'date'] = df.loc[len(df.index) - 1, 'date'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin()
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
         date
0  2015-10-01
1  2015-11-01
2  2015-12-01
3  2016-01-01
4  2016-03-01
5  2016-03-01
6  2016-10-01
7  2016-10-01
8  2016-12-01
9  2017-03-01
10 2017-04-01
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [MonthBegin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offset-semantics):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(['2015-11-01','2015-12-01','2016-01-01','2016-03-01','2016-03-01','2016-10-01','2016-10-01','2016-12-01','2017-03-01'],columns=['date'])
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df=pd.DataFrame([df.loc[0,'date'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)]+list(df['date'])+[df.loc[len(df)-1,'date'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)],columns=['date'])
df
```

Output:

```
    date
0   2015-10-01
1   2015-11-01
2   2015-12-01
3   2016-01-01
4   2016-03-01
5   2016-03-01
6   2016-10-01
7   2016-10-01
8   2016-12-01
9   2017-03-01
10  2017-04-01
```